# Mulesoft parallel processing

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

in Mulesoft, I want to take an array of objects and for each of them call an Http endpoint, gathering the results into an array to return to my consumer. I have done this using a ForEach loop and an array. All works ok. But each element in the array calls out to the Http Endpoint and has to wait for a response before going to the next one. The endpoint is the same, albeit a slightly different parameter based on the specific element being processed. What I would like to do is send the request for all objects (or at least a chunk of them, maybe 10 or 20) in parallel, then wait for the responses and gather them together.

I have seen some patterns but they usually rely on knowing specific endpoints for specific elements. ie send this object to this endpoint and that one to that endpoint. Here it is a dynamic array and the endpoints are therefore dynamic. How would this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mulesoft Splitter-Aggregator to achieve said use case. You can refer [Spitter-Aggregator example](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/splitter-flow-control-reference#example-splitting-and-aggregating-with-asynchronous-flows) for more details.

Comment: thanks - I am going to look at this when I get time. Will mark as correct once I have tested

Comment: I have used Splitter-Aggregator for other scenarios where the endpoints are known, but for splitting a collection I ended up using Collection Splitter and Collection Aggregator and Request-Reply VM

Answer (score 1):

You can try using batch processing where you can send a chunk of objects and wait for that entire chunk for the response before moving on to next batch.
Within a Mule application, batch processing stands on its own as an independent block of code. From an external resource, batch accepts sets of data – perhaps polling for the input – to process in chunks.  Batches elegantly handle any record-level failures that might occur in processing so as to prevent failure of a complete batch job.
Further, you can set or remove variables on individual records so that during batch processing, Mule can route or otherwise act upon records in a batch according to a record variable.

For example

```
<batch:job name="myBatchJob">
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Step1"/>
        <batch:step name="Step2"/>
        <batch:step name="Step3"/>
    </batch:process-records>
</batch:job>

<flow name="flowOne">
    ...
</flow>
```

You can refer to [mule doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/batch-processing) for more details

Comment: thanks. I am not sure if I can apply this in my case but will take a look